# OpenCv, Python - Printing the first found mouth

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm running a face detection algorithm on a set of static images that are being loaded sequentialy. I want to print only the first found mouth, to avoid the high amount of false positives. I currently have this:

```
for img in glob.glob('*'):

cvImg = cv2.imread(img,0)
if cvImg is not None:
    images.append(cvImg)
    print len(images)
for img in images:
(...)
    mouths = mouthCascade.detectMultiScale(roiMouth, 1.3, 5)                
    for mouth in mouths:
        (mx, my, mw, mh) = mouth[0]
        cv2.rectangle(roiMouth, (mx, my), (mx+mw, my+mh), (0, 45, 55), 2)
        countMount = countMount + 1
```

But I'm always getting the same error:

> TypeError: 'numpy.int32' object is not iterable

on the line `(mx, my, mw, mh) = mouth[0]`. I just cannot find the right way to do this!

Comment: Won't the first mouth be `mouths[0]`?

Comment: I have a set of images, pre-loaded with glob! so mouths have all mouths detected for all images. I have to run it sequentially

Comment: can u understand now @Divakar ?

Comment: `print mouth[0]` at that line and see what it contains? I am mostly shooting in the dark as I am not really familiar with the output data format from `mouthCascade.detectMultiScale`.

Comment: printing 432 elements. the first ones of the (x,y,w,h) tuple. I want to print the first tuple. not the first element of all mouth tuples.

Answer (score 0):

mouth is a list of rectangles. `(mx, my, mw, mh) = mouth` should do the job.

There are a lot of tutorials online:
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html